# How do I speed up this for loop in r

Tags: r

I can only think an iterative version for the problem statement below. It works, but is very slow. It's an example of flattening data.

For every row in my data frame, I compute this - I have a few values stored in 'agevalues'. There is also an equivalent column for each of these age values, such that, if the value is 50, the equivalent column name is age_50. I check if any of the columns from 'age1' to 'age3' contain values in 'agevalues'. If yes, as in, if the value 50 is present, I set age_250 to 1 for this row.

Please see my solution below

```
age1=c(20,30,30)
age2=c(10,20,45)
age3=c(50,60,70)
df = data.frame(age1,age2,age3)

#finding unique values of age1...age3 columns
agevalues = NULL
for(i in which(names(df) == "age1"):which(names(df) == "age3"))
{
    agevalues = c(agevalues, unique(df[,i]))
}
uniqueagevalues = unique(agevalues)

#creating a column for each of these age buckets
count = 0;
for(i in 1:length(uniqueagevalues))
{
    newcol = paste("age_",as.character(uniqueagevalues[i]),sep=""); 
    print(newcol)
    df[newcol] = 0
    count = count + 1;
}

#putting 1 if present, else 0
count = 0;
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    for(j in 1:length(uniqueagevalues))
    {
        if(length(which(df[i,which(names(df) == "age1"):which(names(df) == "age3")] == uniqueagevalues[j])))
        {
            coltoaddone = paste("age_",as.character(uniqueagevalues[j]),sep="");
            print(coltoaddone)  
            df[i,coltoaddone] = 1;
        }
        count = count + 1;  
    }
}
```

Input

```
> df
  age1 age2 age3
1   20   10   50
2   30   20   60
3   30   45   70
```

Output

```
> df
  age1 age2 age3 age_20 age_30 age_10 age_45 age_50 age_60 age_70
1   20   10   50      1      0      1      0      1      0      0
2   30   20   60      1      1      0      0      0      1      0
3   30   45   70      0      1      0      1      0      0      1
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data to run your code.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, alright give me a couple of minutes. generating sample data

Comment: @docendodiscimus, have edited the question above.

Comment: or just make a table `with(stack(df), ftable(ind, values))` and bind it together if you want `cbind(df, as.matrix(with(stack(df), ftable(ind, values))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative implementation using just one `sapply` loop and some vectorization before and after:

```
# get the unique age values:
agevalues <- unique(unname(unlist(df)))
# check which agevalues are present in which row:
m <- sapply(agevalues, function(x) as.integer(rowSums(df == x) > 0L))
# add the result to the original data and set column names:
df <- setNames(cbind(df, m), c(names(df), paste0("age_", agevalues)))

df
#  age1 age2 age3 age_20 age_30 age_10 age_45 age_50 age_60 age_70
#1   20   10   50      1      0      1      0      1      0      0
#2   30   20   60      1      1      0      0      0      1      0
#3   30   45   70      0      1      0      1      0      0      1
```

#### data:

```
age1=c(20,30,30)
age2=c(10,20,45)
age3=c(50,60,70)
df = data.frame(age1,age2,age3)
```

Edit note: adjusted for cases of multiple matches per row to only return 1 (not the number of matches)

---

Edit after comment:

The conversion to matrix is done by `sapply` because it uses its default `simplify = TRUE` setting. To understand what happens, look at it step by step:

- `sapply(agevalues, ... )` is a loop that feeds one element of agevalues per loop, i.e. it starts at the first element which is 20 in this case.

What happens next is:

```
df == 20    #  (because x == 20 in the first loop)
#      age1  age2  age3
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE      # 1 TRUE in this row
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE      # 1 TRUE in this row
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE      # 0 TRUE in this row
```

At this stage you already have a matrix indicating where the condition is TRUE. Then, you wrap this in `rowSums` and what happens is:

```
rowSums(df == 20)
#[1] 1 1 0
```

It tells you how many matches there were per row. Note that, if there were 2 or more matches in a row, `rowSums` would return a value >1 for that row. Because you only want 0 or 1 entries returned, you can check on the `rowSums` whether the elements are 0 (no matches) or >0 (any number of matches greater than or equal to 1):

```
rowSums(df == agevalues[1]) > 0L
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As you see, this returns a logical vector with TRUE/FALSE entries. Since you want 0/1 in your final output, you can convert the logicals to integers using:

```
as.integer(rowSums(df == agevalues[1]) > 0L)
# [1] 1 1 0
```

These are the values you see in the sapply output. And since you do it for each element in agevalues, sapply is able to simplify the result from a list to a matrix like this:

```
sapply(agevalues, function(x) as.integer(rowSums(df == x) > 0L))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

Note that, if you specified `simplify = FALSE` in the `sapply`, you would get a list in return:

```
sapply(agevalues, function(x) as.integer(rowSums(df == x) > 0L), simplify = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 0 0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 1

[[5]]
[1] 1 0 0

[[6]]
[1] 0 1 0

[[7]]
[1] 0 0 1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't benchmark with the original post but it should be a nice performance improvement already.

Comment: Thanks, @ColonelBeauvel. Yours answer is also a good suggestion.

Comment: I was also turning around cut, but rowSums is clever there! Best way to go.

Comment: @docendodiscimus , thanks. I have understood the first and third line. I've been trying hard to understand the second line for some time, but don't get it completely. What does rowSums(df == x) > 0L) do ? How does it produce a 0-1 matrix?

Comment: @IAMTubby, I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: @docendodiscimus , thank you so much, that is wonderful explanation. I had spent some time trying to understand it piece by piece and after reading your explanation made it so much more clearer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `mtabulate` from **qdapTools**

```
library(qdapTools)
df1 <- mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df)))
names(df1) <- paste('age', names(df1), sep="_")
cbind(df, df1)
#  age1 age2 age3 age_10 age_20 age_30 age_45 age_50 age_60 age_70
#1   20   10   50      1      1      0      0      1      0      0
#2   30   20   60      0      1      1      0      0      1      0
#3   30   45   70      0      0      1      1      0      0      1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(age1 = c(20L, 30L, 30L), age2 = c(10L, 20L, 45L
), age3 = c(50L, 60L, 70L)), .Names = c("age1", "age2", "age3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
labels = paste("age",unique(unlist(df)), sep='_')
lst    = lapply(data.frame(t(df)), function(u) as.integer(labels %in% paste("age",u,sep='_')))
setNames(cbind(df,do.call(rbind, lst)),c(names(df),labels))

#   age1 age2 age3 age_20 age_30 age_10 age_45 age_50 age_60 age_70
#X1   20   10   50      1      0      1      0      1      0      0
#X2   30   20   60      1      1      0      0      0      1      0
#X3   30   45   70      0      1      0      1      0      0      1
```